GLPI with AlmaLinux and plesk
If I have not misunderstood the official installation instructions, including the specific section on locating directories with information
Adapting to an AlmaLinux server with Plesk to install GLPI on https://subdomain.yourdomain.com
Directory extracted from the installation file:
/var/www/glpi >> /var/www/vhosts/yourdomain.com/subdomain/ 

Directories moved out of the public folder (I have also tried using /public/ as vhost root)
/etc/glpi     >> /var/www/vhosts/yourdomain.com/internal/config
/var/lib/glpi >> /var/www/vhosts/yourdomain.com/internal/files
/var/www/vhosts/yourdomain.com/internal/marketplace

Created file inc/downstream.php
<?php
define('GLPI_CONFIG_DIR', '/var/www/vhosts/yourdomain.com/internal/config');

if (file_exists(GLPI_CONFIG_DIR . '/local_define.php')) {
   require_once GLPI_CONFIG_DIR . '/local_define.php';
}

Created file config/local_define.php
<?php
define('GLPI_VAR_DIR', '/var/www/vhosts/yourdomain.com/internal/files');
define('GLPI_LOG_DIR', '/var/www/vhosts/yourdomain.com/logs/subdomain'); // Plesk original log folder

Additional NGINX directives, without Apache proxy mode (I also tried activating and processing .htaccess with the same problems):
location / {
    # Todas las solicitudes se redirigen a /public/index.php
    rewrite ^ /public/index.php last;
}

location ~ ^/public/index\.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/plesk/plesk-php82-fpm.sock; # Ajustar según tu entorno
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;
}
#some tests
#location ~ ^/(?!public/).* {
    #   deny all;
    #}

    location /public {
        try_files $uri =404;
    }

    location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|otf|eot|map)$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
    }
    // It is not documented, but I don't think it should be accessible    
    location = /status.php {
        allow 127.0.0.1; # Permitir acceso desde localhost
        deny all;
        return 404;
    }

Other additional information that could be interesting:

PHP-FPM 8.3.14
AlmaLinux 9.5 (Teal Serval)
GLPI 10.0.17

open_basedir (PHP):
{WEBSPACEROOT}{/}{:}{TMP}{/}:/var/www/vhosts/yourdomain.com/subdomain/public:/var/www/vhosts/yourdomain.com/subdomain:/var/www/vhosts/yourdomain.com/internal/config:/var/www/vhosts/yourdomain.com/internal/files:/var/www/vhosts/yourdomain.com/internal/install

Still showing the error on the home screen about folder security...

Web server root directory configuration is not safe as it permits
access to non-public files. See installation documentation for more
details.


What should be the correct configuration in this scenario?
NOTE 1: Modifying the function that checks security is not an option... glpi/src/system/Requirement/safedocumentroot.php
NOTE 2: The official documentation refers to inc\based_config.php files but the operation of the variables should be the same v10.x, (removed on beta v11.X).


What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Is this really a problem with nginx or plesk, as in: this would work different when not using these tools?

If you compare with the official documentation, I have adapted the NGINX directives to Plesk, modified and created the directory configuration files, changed the publishing directory of the website to root path, public, the PHP open_basedir parameters (not done reference either)... the files are not accessible but the warning message continues to be displayed...

Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. Also, share how this problem is related to programming (for example, by adding the code involved)

You can try temporarily modifying the glpi\src\System\Requirement\RequirementInterface.php file to include the values of $initial_script, realpath($initial_script), GLPI_ROOT, sprintf('%s/public/index.php', GLPI_ROOT), and realpath(sprintf('%s/public/index.php', GLPI_ROOT)) in the diagnostic message. This might help shed some light on what's happening. Additionally, it would be better to share the full nginx server block instead (you can view it using the nginx -T command).

Modifying an interface type class does not seem like the most appropriate place to add debug variables... I just added the Github link to the function that performs the directory check
